# sending invalid response on port 25 ubuntu

Tags: jakarta-mail, sendmail

I want to send invalid response on port 25, When somebody wants to send mail such that connection is not timed out and it has to wait for indefinite time. I am java mail library which has by default infinite connection timeout value. Class which I am using is com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport. How can I simulate this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Let me make sure I understand...

You want to write a fake SMTP server that listens on port 25 and sends an invalid response that causes clients to fail immediately when they try to send a message?

I think you need to start by reading the SMTP RFC protocol spec.

You'll find a simple fake SMTP server used for testing in the JavaMail source code workspace; you might be able to use that as a starting point.

Comment: I want an invalid response such that it never fails i.e. it waits for indefinite time

Comment: How long the client waits is up to the client.  I don't think there's anything you can do in the server to make the client wait forever.